# Highlight any cell in a range that matches any cell in another range

Tags: excel, vba

I Have Range1(S4:W8) and Range2(J4:N18).

I want to create a Macro that will check if any cells between the two ranges are equal to each other, and if so, highlight. Depending on the scenario, Range2 may have few, or many blank cells.

Below is My attempt. "*****" is a placeholder for me because I don't know what to put there.

```
Dim R1 As Range
Set R1 = Range("S4:W8")

Dim R2 As Range
Set R2 = Range("J4:N18")

For Each Cell In R1
        If Cell.Value ***** Then
            Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            
        End If
    Next


End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using conditional formatting?

Comment: Should we understand that "are equal to each other" means that they exist in both ranges? Being ranges with different number of rows, being equal on the same row is not an option. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad volatile function, though probably not a big deal given the rather small range of checks.

Comment: @FaneDuru Correct, they exist in both ranges, but if a value exists in both ranges it may not be in the same position in each range

Comment: What does **in the same position** should mean. Was my understanding that the ranges **do not have the same dimensions** a wrong one? Now, reading again your question (its words) it looks that I misunderstood this aspect. So, in other words, should  the  the cell interior be colored **only if the third cell on the first row of the first range is equal with the third one in the first row of the second range**? In words you say that they are equal, but **Range1(S4:W8) and Range2(J4:N18)** are obviously not equal. Which statement is the correct one? Did you miss 1? To be **S4:W18**?

Comment: But, if the same values **exist in both ranges, independent of their position in each range**, the code I supplied does color the cells based on this logic. What's wrong with the processing result. I edited the answer and placed another piece of code checking the same positions... I am a little confused about what you really want accomplishing.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of ways to do this, but here's a simple method that might help you with understanding loops and ranges. I presume you don't want to use conditional formatting for something like this.

I changed up your variables a little for clarity, and added an `exit for` since once you match a color no need to keep searching.

```
Sub doTHis()
Dim aRng As Range, gRng As Range, aCell As Range, gCell As Range

'probably should scope the sheet too

Set aRng = Range("S4:W8")
Set gRng = Range("J4:N18")

For Each aCell In aRng.Cells
        For Each gCell In gRng.Cells
            If gCell.Value = aCell.Value Then
                aCell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
                Exit For ' no need to keep searching
            End If
        Next gCell
Next aCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, test the next way. It should be very fast for large ranges, using arrays, placing the cells to be colored in a Union range and color them at the code end. It also skips the empty cells to be compared:

```
Sub testMatchRngValues()
Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, rngCol As Range, arr1, arr2, i As Long, j As Long, i1 As Long, j1 As Long

Set R1 = Range("S4:W8"):  arr1 = R1.Value  'place the range in an array for faster interation
Set R2 = Range("J4:N18"): arr2 = R2.Value  'place the range in an array for faster interation

For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
        For i1 = 1 To UBound(arr2)
            For j1 = 1 To UBound(arr2, 2)
                If arr1(i, j) = arr2(i1, j1) And arr1(i, j) <> "" Then
                    If rngCol Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngCol = R1.cells(i, j)
                    Else
                        Set rngCol = Union(rngCol, R1.cells(i, j))
                    End If
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next j1
        Next i1
    Next j
Next i
If Not rngCol Is Nothing Then rngCol.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Not tested, but it should work as you need...

If your ranges are really equal in terms of rows/columns, as you say in your comment, please try the next code:

```
Sub testMatchRngValues2()
 Dim R1 As Range, R2 As Range, rngCol As Range, arr1, arr2, i As Long, j As Long

 Set R1 = Range("S4:W18"):  arr1 = R1.Value  'place the range in an array for faster interation
 Set R2 = Range("J4:N18"): arr2 = R2.Value  'place the range in an array for faster interation
 R1.Interior.color = xlNone 'clear any cell interior color
 For i = 1 To UBound(arr1)
    For j = 1 To UBound(arr1, 2)
            If arr1(i, j) = arr2(i, j) And arr1(i, j) <> "" Then
                    If rngCol Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngCol = R1.cells(i, j)
                    Else
                        Set rngCol = Union(rngCol, R1.cells(i, j))
                    End If
            End If
    Next j
 Next i
 If Not rngCol Is Nothing Then rngCol.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want simplicity over performance, you could use this code:

```
Sub findInRange()

    Dim R1 As Range
    Set R1 = Range("S4:W8")

    Dim R2 As Range
    Set R2 = Range("J4:N18")

    Dim fnd As Range

    ' search R2 for cell in R1
    For Each cell In R1

        Set fnd = R2.Find(cell.Value, lookat:=xlWhole)
        
        If Not fnd Is Nothing Then
            ' colour matched cells
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
        Else
            ' reset colour in unmatched cells
            cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 0
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Highlight Column Matches

[image]

- This will highlight matches per column i.e. each range has the same number of columns, so it will find matches of the cells in columns of the source range in cells in the respective columns of the destination range and highlight them in yellow.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub HighlightColumnMatches()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = ws.Range("J4:N18")
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ws.Range("S4:W8")
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = drg.Rows.Count
    Dim dData As Variant: dData = drg.Value
    
    Dim scrg As Range
    Dim sIndex As Variant
    Dim durg As Range
    Dim dr As Long
    Dim dc As Long
    
    For dc = 1 To drg.Columns.Count
        Set scrg = srg.Columns(dc)
        For dr = 1 To drCount
            sIndex = Application.Match(dData(dr, dc), scrg, 0)
            If IsNumeric(sIndex) Then
                If durg Is Nothing Then
                    Set durg = drg.Cells(dr, dc)
                Else
                    Set durg = Union(durg, drg.Cells(dr, dc))
                End If
            End If
        Next dr
    Next dc
                
    If Not durg Is Nothing Then
        drg.Interior.Color = xlNone
        durg.Interior.Color = vbYellow
    End If

    MsgBox "Matches highlighted.", vbInformation

End Sub
```